# Replacing the · symbol

Tags: javascript

I've currently got a genuinely bizarre issue.

Facebook uses the · symbol liberally. I'm trying to replace it with a regular hypen, but I've got a... strange error.

If I put "·" in my HTML document it displays as "Â·" on the page. If I put "Â·" in the document it displays as "Ã‚Â·" on the page. If I put "Ã‚Â·" in the document is displays as "Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â·" on the page. If I put "Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â·" in the document it displays as "ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â·" on the page. I assume this continues happening.

I think this is the cause of my issue, but basically I'm wanting to be able to put "·" in a textbox and have Javascript change it to "-". For the sake of completeness here is my full code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="display"></div><br/>
        <input type=textbox id="text_in"/>
        <input type=submit onclick='replaceDots()'/>

        <script>
            function replaceDots() {
                var text_in = document.getElementById("text_in").value;
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = text_in.replace("·","-");    
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I put in the · symbol is displays · in the output. Curiously though, if I set text_in in the function to be equal to '·' it displays a hyphen in the output. This is why I the Â· error is to blame, though honestly this has me stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome in the world of unicode. You have written a unicode (UTF-8) `·` symbol in your document. This symbol consists of multiple code units (bytes, in this case) but it's `Content-Type` is set to an Ansi codepage, causing each of those bytes to be displayed as separate Ansi characters. See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I blogged an intro to Unicode once - http://kos.gd/2013/02/say-hello-to-unicode/

Comment: You guys are my hero, thank you.

Comment: middle dot, `&middot;` or `&#183;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the escaped value instead.  Replace your line with this:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = text_in.replace("&#183;","-");
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'll take a look to see if I can fix it.  Sorry about that.